# Почему не работает cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');?

Tags: c++, input, cin

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

struct CandyBar {
    string name;
    double weight;
    int calories;
};

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    CandyBar arr[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << "Введите название " << i+1 << " коробки: ";
        getline(cin, arr[i].name);
        cout << "Введите вес " << i+1 << " коробки: ";
        cin >> arr[i].weight;
        cout << "Введите число каллорий " << i+1 << " коробки: ";
        cin >> arr[i].calories;
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << "Данные о " << i + 1 << " коробке:\n";
        cout << "Название: " << arr[i].name << endl;
        cout << "Вес: " << arr[i].weight << endl;
        cout << "Число калорий: " << arr[i].calories << endl;
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

**В строке cin.ignore(numeric_limits::max(), '\n'); max() помечается как ошибка: требуется идентификатор. Как это исправить?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут происходит конфликт макросов `min` `max` из заголовочных файлов Windows и одноименных функций из стандартной библиотеки. Для того чтобы в заголовочных файлах Windows не объявлялись эти макросы достаточно при сборке (или перед включением этих заголовочных файлов) определить препроцессорную директиву `NOMINMAX`.

Comment: В начале файла написал `#define NOMIXMAX` но это не помогло

Comment: @JustLearn * `NOMINMAX`

Comment: спасибо, теперь работает

Answer (score 2):

Проблема была из-за max, который есть и в `windows.h`
Решение:
Добавить

```
#ifdef max
#undef max
#endif
```

Но это решение меня не очень устраивает, т.к. получается если мне понадобится max() из windows.h, то я не смогу им воспользоваться. Есть ли какие-то другие решения проблемы?

Comment: Не использовать windows (или C++? А лучше и то и другое вместе)

Comment: @avp очень информативно

Comment: Пока, наверное, нет. Но лет через 20 (если все еще будете активно разрабатывать софт поймете о чем я говорю)

Comment: Можно разнести по разным cpp-файлам код, использующий winapi, и код, не использующий его. Тогда макрос из windows.h не будет мешать другим частям программы.

Comment: Зачем Вам `min`/`max` из Windows.h? Пользуйтесь `std::min`, `std::max`